# AddTriggerEffect on Media Bookmark

Tags: vba, powerpoint, vba7

I am having issues with using VBA to make an audio track start on another's bookmark. I have tried looking into `AddTriggerEffect` and `msoAnimTriggerOnMediaBookmark`, but none of my research is working.

I am running pptm on a macbook pro.

I have looked at these sites and more:

- https://www.skphub.com/2010/ppt002.htm
- http://skp.mvps.org/2010/ppt002.htm
- https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/office/vba/api/powerpoint.msoanimeffect
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.sequence.addtriggereffect

My most common issue is "Method or data member not found" in response to:
`.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add.AddTriggerEffect`

At this point, I can figure out how to customize my animations in every way, except for making one run through a bookmark via vba. Please lmk if you have ay further questions.